# I want to check bluetooth status periodically

Tags: android, bluetooth

This is my code.

I am trying to connect android to arduino. 
but I want to check bluetooth status because user can turn off bluetooth.
at that time, I dont want that bluetooth status bar remained 'connected'.

I tried to use Thread instead of BroadcastReceiver. then my code causes no error, But Thread doesn't work.

maybe when calling bluetooth activity, Thread can't do something.

is it better to use BroadcastReceiver?

```
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;

private BluetoothThread btThread;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }       

    bluetoothConnect();

    btThread = new BluetoothThread();
    btThread.start();


}


private void bluetoothConnect() {

        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            changeBtStatus(CONNECTING);
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

        } else{ 
            changeBtStatus(CONNECTED);
            ensureDiscoverable();
        }


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            changeBtStatus(CONNECTED);
            ensureDiscoverable();
        } else{
            changeBtStatus(DISCONNECTED);

        }
    }
}

class BluetoothThread extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.run();

        while(true){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                bluetoothConnect();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                //do noop
            }
        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not use a Thread, you will be wasting battery constantly with your app, the best thing to do is to have a listener that notifies your app when the bluetooth have turned off. There is an interface for that.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener.html

Comment: Give it a try and if it works, comment here with your implementation, its always good to learn something new.